# Thymeleaf fragments not being resolved

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

So I've trying to use fragments but it seems like there is a problem resolving the fragment itself. I'm guessing it is a fragment resolver issue as the code for the fragment should be right but shouldn't the fragment resolver be auto-configured? Any help is appreciated!

Error

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving
> template [fragments/navbar], template might not exist or might not be
> accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template:
> "flights-listOneWay" - line 15, col 6)

Main html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title>Chrono Airlines</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="fragments/navbar :: navigation"></div>
----more html below----
```

Fragment. Placed under resources/fragments/navbar.html

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <div th:fragment="navigation">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Chrono Airlines</a>
              </div>
              <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                  <li class="active"><a href="/">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of the fragment you have to also give it a name.
In your case add these 2 lines on top. (Don’t forget to close this new div)

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<div th:fragment="navigation">
```

And in the first document replace should be nameOfTheFile::fragmentName

```
th:replace="fragments/navbar::navigation"
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I'm still getting the error

Comment: Did you close the new div?

Comment: Yes I did, I posted the new html in my question

Comment: Wait are both files in folder templates? As in main file right under templates and the other one In src/resources/templates /fragments? It is a relative pathe so folder fragments should be right next to the main file

Comment: main file under src/main/resources/templates/main.html fragment is resources/fragments/navbar.html

Comment: Well that is why please put fragments folder into templates